# sqlite3 method access exception in wp7 while storing database in isolatedstorage

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-7

I'm currently developing database app for wp7& 8 in wp8 Sdk with target Os 7.1.When i Run the Application in Wvga,wxga,720p emulator all working fine,but when i run it on 7.1 Emulator,An unhandled exception of type 'System.MethodAccessException' occurred in Community.CsharpSqlite.WinPhone.dll exception is Thrown at the sqlite.cs file in  return the code **(Result)Sqlite3.sqlite3_open_v2(filename, out db, flags, null);**.Help me to solve this Problem

for reference have a look at it
[image]

Comment: Can we see more of the code that throws the error?

Comment: The  Sqlite library was  downloaded from https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net ,i just posted this issue there 3 days ago,but still there is no response there,i even tried in creating another project but the same issue persist

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is useful to you, but I fixed this problem in the end by, well, switching to csharp-sqlite :)

You may also peek into sqlite-net sources and remove the offending call, but the csharp-sqlite project  has more activity and generally less problems.

Comment: please provide me a sample for that one